# PTIJ: How to be like Yoav

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

It says in [Pesikta Rabbati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesikta_Rabbati) [11](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesikta_Rabbati.11.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> ואתה מוצא חכם יושב ראשו של סנהדרין היה יושב בשבת תחכמוני (שם כ"ג ח') הוא היה יואב שהיה גדול בתורה וגיבור במלחמה:‏
>
> You find a scholar who sits as the head of Sanhedrin who was Yoshev B'Shevet the Tach'kmonite. He was Yoav who was great in Torah and strong in war.

We see from here that Yoav was a great person. So my question is: How can I be as much like Yoav as possible?

Answer (score 1):

1. [Learn from a careless teacher, then threaten to kill him (or maybe actually do so)](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.21b.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he).
2. [Make 2 (or 3) mistakes](https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.12a.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he).

Comment: Re #2 - they have to be simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a plan which will cause me to have four things in common with Yoav. First, I have to become the *Kohen Gadol*. Afterwards, I have to engineer it so that someone will accidentally kill my brother, and I need to accidentally kill his brother by striking him in the fifth rib. After all this is magically accomplished, the person who killed my brother will have to have a duel with me. I have to make sure he doesn't win, or he will get off scot-free after the *Kohen Gadol* dies. After killing him by striking him in the fifth rib, I will have to live in an *Ir Miklat* for the rest of my life, and pray for myself to die in the *Kodesh HaKadashim* every *Yom Kippur*. Then, I will have four things in common with Yoav: I will have won a battle, become a successful *Go'el HaDam*, killed two people by striking them in the fifth rib, and hoped to die in the *Mishkan/Beis HaMikdash*.

Comment: Well, that’s morbid.